# Running Worksheet_Calculate on 2 different worksheets at the same time

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 tables on 2 different worksheets I need to be controlled by VBA code. THe purpose of this code is resize and format these tables depending on slicer selection.

The code works when I run each one at a time. However, when I try to run them simultaneously, I get an error message: "Select method of Range class failed", because I think this is attempting to run VBA code on 2 different ranges.

Here is the code for one of my tables:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ob As ListObject
Dim Lrow1 As Long
Dim rngBottomRowStart As Range
Dim rngBottomRowEnd As Range
Dim rngDataUpperLeftCell As Range

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Slide 1")
Set ob = ws.ListObjects("Table6")

Set rngDataUpperLeftCell = Sheet18.Range("A19")
With rngDataUpperLeftCell
    Set rngBottomRowStart = Sheet18.Cells(.End(xlDown).Row, .Column)
    Set rngBottomRowEnd = Sheet18.Cells(rngBottomRowStart.Row, .End(xlToRight).Column)
End With

Sheet18.Range(rngBottomRowStart, rngBottomRowEnd).Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
Sheet18.Range(rngBottomRowStart, rngBottomRowEnd).Font.Bold = False

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Slide 1")
Set ob = ws.ListObjects("Table6")

With Sheets("Slide 1")
    Lrow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    Do Until .Cells(Lrow1, "A").Value = "Region Total"
        Lrow1 = Lrow1 - 1
    Loop

End With

ob.Resize ob.Range.Resize(Lrow1 + 1 - ob.Range.Row)

Set rngDataUpperLeftCell = Sheet18.Range("A19")
With rngDataUpperLeftCell
    Set rngBottomRowStart = Sheet18.Cells(.End(xlDown).Row, .Column)
    Set rngBottomRowEnd = Sheet18.Cells(rngBottomRowStart.Row, .End(xlToRight).Column)
End With

Sheet18.Range(rngBottomRowStart, rngBottomRowEnd).Select
With Selection
    With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With
End With

Sheet18.Range(rngBottomRowStart, rngBottomRowEnd).Font.Bold = True
Range("A19").Select


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

and the code for my 2nd table:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ob As ListObject
Dim Lrow1 As Long
Dim rngBottomRowStart As Range
Dim rngBottomRowEnd As Range
Dim rngDataUpperLeftCell As Range

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Slide 4 Test")
Set ob = ws.ListObjects("Table58")

Set rngDataUpperLeftCell = Sheet19.Range("A10")
With rngDataUpperLeftCell
    Set rngBottomRowStart = Sheet19.Cells(.End(xlDown).Row, .Column)
    Set rngBottomRowEnd = Sheet19.Cells(rngBottomRowStart.Row, .End(xlToRight).Column)
End With

Sheet19.Range(rngBottomRowStart, rngBottomRowEnd).Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
Sheet19.Range(rngBottomRowStart, rngBottomRowEnd).Font.Bold = False

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Slide 4 Test")
Set ob = ws.ListObjects("Table58")

With Sheets("Slide 4 Test")
    Lrow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    Do Until .Cells(Lrow1, "A").Value = "Region Total"
        Lrow1 = Lrow1 - 1
    Loop

End With

ob.Resize ob.Range.Resize(Lrow1 + 1 - ob.Range.Row)

Set rngDataUpperLeftCell = Sheet19.Range("A10")
With rngDataUpperLeftCell
    Set rngBottomRowStart = Sheet19.Cells(.End(xlDown).Row, .Column)
    Set rngBottomRowEnd = Sheet19.Cells(rngBottomRowStart.Row, .End(xlToRight).Column)
End With

Sheet19.Range(rngBottomRowStart, rngBottomRowEnd).Select
With Selection
    With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With
End With

Sheet19.Range(rngBottomRowStart, rngBottomRowEnd).Font.Bold = True
Range("A10").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

How do i combine this code so that it will on run different sheets without error?

Comment: Get rid of selection. Refer ranges directly, e.g. 
`With Sheet19.Range(rngBottomRowStart, rngBottomRowEnd)` instead of `Sheet19.Range(rngBottomRowStart, rngBottomRowEnd).Select` and `With Selection`

Comment: I didn't check the code, but this error is common when you try to select cell in inactive sheet.